# I ran `Rails console` and the output in my console doesn't match the console output in a textbook Im reading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, match

Im reading a textbook called: "RailsSpace: Building a Social Networking website with Ruby on Rails" by Michael Hartl. The book is available free for download, here is a link so you can follow along and maybe the book can help you investigate and find an answer to my question: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ca98/3b5098cd5957dc1842bb4bf3175406624bca.pdf?_ga=2.121598472.1814901715.1569094472-1963651489.1569094472. start on page 75 under "The Console" section, and you can maybe read a litte bit before that to get a feel for what is going on. Anyhow, my problem is that,

> when I run the code:

`rails server`

in my command prompt,

> the output on my console shows this:

`Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.0)
irb(main):001:0>`

> And the console output in the textbook shows this:

```
`Loading development environment.
>> user = User.new(:screen_name => "me",
?> :email => "",
?> :password => "a")
=> #<User:0xb76fadd0 @new_record=true,
@attributes={"screen_name"=>"me", "password"=>"a", "email"=>""}>
>> user.screen_name
=> "me"

>> user.save
=> true`
```

Does anybody know why the console output in my command prompt doesn't match the console output in the textbook? I dont expect it to be exactly the same but at least closer than that. As you can see my screen hardly shows anything. The book is old, published around 2007, but its practically one of the only FREE sources out there for building a social media website, its pretty much all I have so I have to work with it. Can someone help me figure out how to get the console output in my command prompt to match the console output in the textbook. Again the console output for the textbook starts on page 75. Thank you guys so much I really apreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type the stuff after >> (the prompt). The things after ?> indicate a continuation, but can be done all in the same line as the >>. The stuff after the => is the output. So this means that after the console has loaded, you need to type:

`user = User.new(:screen_name => "me", :email => "", :password => "a")`

Which will create a new user, and output something like:

`#<User:0xb76fadd0 @new_record=true, @attributes={"screen_name"=>"me", "password"=>"a", "email"=>""}>`

Then, you should type:

`user.screen_name`

Etc...

Do not be overly concerned if everything doesn't look *exactly* the same - different versions and platforms may have subtle differences.

Comment: As a side-note, you may wish to run through the official guides at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html as an easier and more up-to-date introduction to the features of the framework, and then build upon that knowledge to make a more complicated app.

Comment: Hey thanks everything worked out just fine after doing that. Lol I had no idea. Results are a whole lot better thanks!

Comment: Right on! I've been seeing your questions come through today - let me assure you that getting it all set up the first time is probably the hardest part. Good luck!